# Grouping documents by Range in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on MongoDB to get the record by query filtering with the endpoints like http://localhost:8000/api/data?c=AT&a=2021-W01&b=2021-W20 I got the result perfectly like

My MongoDB Query :

```
{
    $match:{ ReportingCountry:c,
    YearWeekISO:{$gte:a,$lt:b}}
}
```

Result

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62f8e16fd2c20d2eb6165bf0",
        "YearWeekISO": "2021-W01",
        "ReportingCountry": "AT",
        "Denominator": "7388778",
        "NumberDosesReceived": "0",
        "NumberDosesExported": "0",
        "FirstDose": "0",
        "SecondDose": "0",
        "DoseAdditional1": "0",
        "DoseAdditional2": "0",
        "UnknownDose": "0",
        "Region": "AT",
        "TargetGroup": "ALL",
        "Vaccine": "MOD",
        "Population": "8932664",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "62f8e16fd2c20d2eb6165c0a",
        "YearWeekISO": "2021-W01",
        "ReportingCountry": "AT",
        "Denominator": "3002329",
        "NumberDosesReceived": "0",
        "NumberDosesExported": "0",
        "FirstDose": "0",
        "SecondDose": "0",
        "DoseAdditional1": "0",
        "DoseAdditional2": "0",
        "UnknownDose": "0",
        "Region": "AT",
        "TargetGroup": "Age25_49",
        "Vaccine": "JANSS",
        "Population": "8932664",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "62f8e16fd2c20d2eb6165c23",
        "YearWeekISO": "2021-W01",
        "ReportingCountry": "AT",
        "Denominator": "753524",
        "NumberDosesReceived": "0",
        "NumberDosesExported": "0",
        "FirstDose": "0",
        "SecondDose": "0",
        "DoseAdditional1": "0",
        "DoseAdditional2": "0",
        "UnknownDose": "0",
        "Region": "AT",
        "TargetGroup": "Age70_79",
        "Vaccine": "JANSS",
        "Population": "8932664",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

But the next step is to group date by range if I enter five the query like
http://localhost:8000/api/data?c=AT&a=2021-W19&b=2021-W20&range=5
the result should come up like

```
{
"summary": [
{
"weekStart": "2020-W10",
"weekEnd": "2020-W15",
"NumberDosesReceived": 1000
},
{
"weekStart": "2020-W15",
"weekEnd": "2020-W20"
"NumberDosesReceived": 2000 } ,
… till end of range (dateTo)
]
```

How can I acheive this with Mongodb

Answer (score 0):

It should work

const YearWeekISO = { $toDate: "$YearWeekISO" };

```js
{
        $project: {
          fiveWeekperiod: {
            $subtract: [
              { $week: YearWeekISO },
              { $mod: [{ $week: YearWeekISO }, 5] },
            ],
          },
          date: YearWeekISO,
          NumberDosesReceived: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            year: { $year: "$date" },
            fiveWeek: "$fiveWeekperiod",
          },
          weekStart: { $min: "$date" },
          weekEnd: { $max: "$date" },
          NumberDosesReceived: { $sum: "$NumberDosesReceived" },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          weekStart: {
            $dateToString: {
              date: "$weekStart",
              format: "%G-W%V",
            },
          },
          weekEnd: {
            $dateToString: {
              date: {
                $dateAdd: {
                  startDate: "$weekEnd",
                  unit: "week",
                  amount: 1,
                },
              },
              format: "%G-W%V",
            },
          },
          NumberDosesReceived: 1,
        },
      }
```